# There's a kernel i can't delete or choose in jupyterlab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-lab

There's a kernel called 'ml' i can't delete or choose in jupyterlab.

[jupyter picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq55x.jpg)

I created the env 'ml', and i couldn't remember whether i delete it.One day i found i can't choose it in jupyterlab, with the error message below:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\editc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1699, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "C:\Users\editc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\editc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 72, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "C:\Users\editc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\editc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\editc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\editc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\editc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\editc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\editc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\editc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Users\editc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\editc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\editc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 259, in start_kernel
    **kw)
  File "C:\Users\editc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 204, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\editc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 138, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\editc\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\editc\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] 系统找不到指定的文件。
```

I tried to reinstall the anaconda and delete all the files of anaconda, it still there and i can't delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just find how to solve it.
`jupyter-kernelspec list`
Then I can see the path of 'ml', and just delete it.